# How to populate Yii2 Autocomplete with AJAX call

Tags: autocomplete, yii2

I am trying to switch to Yii2 from Yii 1.1. This was source attribute of TextAreaJuiAutoComplete widget

```
'source'=>"js:function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON('".$url"', {
        term: extractLast(request.term)
    }, response);
}",
```

This is not working in Yii2 with yii\jui\AutoComplete anymore. Can anyone give me a hint what is the cause? Underlying JavaScript objects should be the same.

If I put following code it works, but I want to use ajax calls instead.

```
'source' => [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ],
```

Comment: Please inspect your javascript with firebug and see the error

Comment: There is no error, just nothing happens.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
use yii\web\JsExpression;

.....
.....


'source'=>new JsExpression("function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON('".$url."', {
        term: request.term
    }, response);
}"),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AutoComplete::widget([
    'name'=>'myacfield',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'source' => Url::to(['autocomplete']),
             'minLength'=>'2',
         ],
    'options'=>[
        'class' => 'form-control'
    ]
]);
```

But your `AutoComplete` action must return a one dimensional array like

```
...            
$rs = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
$row_set = [];
foreach ($rs as $row)
{
    $row_set[] = $row['name']; //build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
```

Answer (score 0):

Examle with like.
Controller:

```
 public function actionSearch($term)
        {
            \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            $rs = Cure::find()->where(['like', 'name_uz', $term])->all();
           if($rs !=null){
               $row_set = [];
               foreach ($rs as $row)
               {
                   $row_set[] = $row->name_uz; //build an array
               }
               return $row_set;
           }else{
               false;
           }

        }
```

In view:

```
<? use yii\jui\AutoComplete;?>
<?= AutoComplete::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'country',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
    'clientOptions' => [
        'source' => Url::to(['cure/search']),
        'minLength'=>'2',
    ],
]); ?>
```